# $x^2-2y^2=8k+1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$k\in N^+$.

Does there exists positive integer solutions (x,y) of Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=8k+1$for any $k$?

If $8k+1$ is a prime, there exists positive integer solutions.

[See Here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210415/pell-equation-of-the-special-form)

[See Here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197918/what-is-known-about-primes-of-the-form-x2-2y2)

But for other numbers,I have tried several ways to solve the  equation and finally  failed.

Any ideas?

A waiting the reply.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312396/x2-2y2-8k1?noredirect=1#comment6815025_3312396) for the same (deleted) question.

Answer (score 2):

No, there does not exist a solution for any $k$. Here is a counterexample. The equation has no solution for $k=4$, i.e., 
$$x^2-2y^2=33$$ has no integer solution. The same holds for $k=7$. If $8k+1$ is a perfect square, there is always a solution with $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If an odd number $n$ is  divisible only by primes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8,$ then it can be expressed in integers as $n = x^2 - 2 y^2.$

For any prime $q \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8,$ there is no expression for $q$ as $u^2 - 2 v^2.$ With an odd exponent $w = 2k+1,$ there is also no expression for $q^w$ as $u^2 - 2 v^2.$ An even exponent here produces a square so that can be expressed with $v=0$

Put together, an odd number $n$ can be expressed if and only if the exponent of prime $q |n$ is even, whenever $q \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8.$

In Dietrich's example, note how $33 = 3 \cdot 11,$ while $3 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ and $11 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$

Comment: How to prove : For any prime $q \equiv \pm 3 \pmod 8,$ there is no expression for $q$ as $u^2 - 2 v^2.

Comment: @qsa  the values of $t^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 8.$ Thus the values of $-2 s^2 \equiv 0, 6 \pmod 8.$ Put them together, $u^2 - 2 v^2 \equiv 0,1,2,4,6,7 \pmod 8.$ I can recommend the recent book    https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: $33=3*11$.Let $q_1=3$ and $q_2=11$.

$q_1,q_2 \equiv  3 \pmod 8$

How to prove:there is no expression for $q_1q_2$ as $u^2 - 2 v^2.$